# How can I adjust Axes sizes in matplotlib polar plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

In making some half polar scatter plots with matplotlib, I found that the figures contained far more white space than the same data plotted on a Cartesian plot.

[image]

[image]

The problem seems to be that the PolarAxes class assumes a data ratio of 1, even for a half polar plot, and I can't find a way to change it.  There is a get_data_ratio operation, but no set_data_ratio.  I marked the 4 corners of the axis in each case with A# and the four corners of the figure with F# to highlight the problem.  In the polar case, the axis corners are nowhere near the corners of the range of the graph, so the vertical extent of the graph limits its overall size.

Can anyone give me guidance on how to adjust the axis to conform more closely to the range of the graph?  The code I used to generate both graphs, based on the matplotlib polar example is below.

```
import argparse
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Plot max particle temperature at initial particle location')
parser.add_argument('--polar', action='store_true', help='use polar grid')
args = parser.parse_args()
polar = args.polar

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# Compute radius and theta
N =100
r = 2 * np.random.rand(N)
theta  = np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
area = 100 * r**2
colors = theta

# Compute Cartesian
x  = r*np.cos(theta)
y  = r*np.sin(theta)

# Choose polar or cartesian plot
if polar:
    coor1=theta
    coor2=r
else:
    coor1=x
    coor2=y

# Create rectangular figure
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

# Create Axis
if polar:
    ax = plt.axes(polar=True)
    ax.set_thetamin(0)
    ax.set_thetamax(180)
else:
    ax = plt.axes()

# Plot data
c = ax.scatter(coor1, coor2, c=colors,   cmap='hsv')

# Set limits

if polar:
    ax.set_rlim(0,2)
else:
    plt.axis('scaled')
    plt.xlim(-2,2)
    plt.ylim(0,2)

ax.annotate('A1',xy=(0, 0),xycoords='axes fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax.annotate('A2',xy=(1, 0),xycoords='axes fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax.annotate('A3',xy=(0, 1),xycoords='axes fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax.annotate('A4',xy=(1, 1),xycoords='axes fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')

ax.annotate('F1',xy=(0, 0),xycoords='figure fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax.annotate('F2',xy=(1, 0),xycoords='figure fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax.annotate('F3',xy=(0, 1),xycoords='figure fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax.annotate('F4',xy=(1, 1),xycoords='figure fraction',horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I will close as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289129/removing-space-around-wedge-polar-plots-in-matplotlib). Though the answer is only a workaround, because [the issue is still not fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10264) in matplotlib. If that workaround is not working for you, best ask a new question, clearly stating in how far that would not be the case.

Comment: Good find.  I thought I searched back more than 6 months on keywords matplotlib and polar, but I missed this one.  Will try the workaround tomorrow.

Comment: ax = plt.axes([-0.6, -0.25, 2.2, 1.5],polar=True)

Comment: So the suggested hack does achieve the desired result, though it's very finicky and needs to be hand-tuned.  Note that there is an easier way, instead of using pyplot.subplots and axis.set_postion as is done in the referenced answer.  In the case of the example I posted, simply replacing ax = plt.axes(polar=True) with ax = plt.axes([-0.6, -0.25, 2.2, 1.5],polar=True) produces a polar grid similar in size to the Cartesian grid pictured in the original question.  Good enough until matplotlib is fixed.