# matplotlib polar plot fill entire figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to create a polar plot inside a matplotlib figure that covers the entire figure. If I use `ax.axis('auto')`, the plot is stretched horizontally but not vertically and the theta axis is not an arc anymore.

I just want to scale the polar plot in such a way that its size is maximized without changing any proportions. To put it in other words, the white space around the polar plot should be removed.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4), tight_layout=True)
ax = figure.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
figure.set_facecolor((0.95, 0.95, 0.95))  # to see the actual figure size

ax.set_thetamin(-10)
ax.set_thetamax(10)

ax.plot(0, 10, 'r*')
```

[image]

Comment: See [Removing space around wedge polar plots in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289129/removing-space-around-wedge-polar-plots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you very much. The `set_position()` command was what I was looking for.